# Linear Algebra: Calculate the dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine which of the following are subspaces of R3. For those that are, determine bases for them and hence calculate their dimension.
(a) All vectors of the form (x,y,z) wherey=x+z.
(b) All vectors of the form(x,y,z)where y=x+z+1.
(c) All points lying in the plane 2x−y+3z=0.
(d) All points in the plane 2x − y = 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that $0$ does not lie in the subset defined in (b), so it is not a subspace.  The rest are kernels of simple transformations from $\mathbb{R}^3$ into
$\mathbb{R}$, so they are subspaces.